# Cant create user over Graph API in Azure AD B2C property not present

Tags: c#, azure, azure-ad-b2c

Currently trying to create a user in a Azure AD B2C over the Graph API but keep getting following error: (I did not delete the property name between the '' there is none...)

```
Code: Request_ResourceNotFound
Message: Resource '' does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are not present.
Inner error:
    AdditionalData:
    date: 2021-10-12T11:22:34
    request-id: f45d65b3-61b1-492c-b6cb-fc43bb3805dd
    client-request-id: f45d65b3-61b1-492c-b6cb-fc43bb3805dd
ClientRequestId: f45d65b3-61b1-492c-b6cb-fc43bb3805dd
```

Following Code is used to create the User

```
IDictionary<string, object> extensionInstance = new Dictionary<string, object>();
extensionInstance.Add($"extension_{AadB2CConfiguration.ExtensionsID}_GUID", guid);

new User
{
    DisplayName = username,
    AccountEnabled = true,
    Identities = new List<ObjectIdentity>
        {
            new ObjectIdentity()
            {
                SignInType = valueSignInType,
                Issuer = AadB2CConfiguration.TenantId,
                IssuerAssignedId = username,

            }
        },
    PasswordPolicies = valuePasswordPolicies,
    PasswordProfile = new PasswordProfile()
    {
        Password = password,
        ForceChangePasswordNextSignIn = false,
    }
    ,AdditionalData = extensionInstance
};
```

GraphClient Method

```
public static Microsoft.Graph.GraphServiceClient GraphClient
        {
            get
            {
                var app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(AadB2CConfiguration.ClientId)
                    .WithClientSecret(AadB2CConfiguration.ClientSecret)
                    .WithAuthority(AadB2CConfiguration.AadB2cGraphAuthority)
                    .Build();

                string[] scopes = new string[] { AadB2CConfiguration.GraphScope };
                var token = app.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes).ExecuteAsync().Result;

                Microsoft.Graph.GraphServiceClient graphClient = new Microsoft.Graph.GraphServiceClient(AadB2CConfiguration.GraphBaseUrl, new Microsoft.Graph.DelegateAuthenticationProvider(async (requestMessage) =>
                {
                    requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", token.AccessToken);
                }));

                return graphClient;
            }
```

The User will then be created via the GraphClient

```
User result = await GraphClient.Users.Request().AddAsync(newUser);
return ResponseMessage(result);
```

How can I find out which property is not present?

Comment: Can you post more of the code you're using to create the user, particularly what's in `extensionInstance` and how you're using the new user - is it passed to a POST request or a PATCH request in (I assume) the Graph SDK?

Comment: @DaveD I added some more information, i have currently 2 separated tenants with the first one i have no problem creating users with the second one i get the mentioned error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that `AadB2CConfiguration.ExtensionsID` is correct, it should be the application (client) ID of the application the `GUID` extension property was created against with the `-` removed.

If it's wrong, and so Graph can't find the application, then you'll get the error `Resource '' does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are not present.`

Comment: yeah thanks a lot! I did know that the - has to be removed but totally forgot it. Do you know why the Client ID can have - chars but not the extension id ?

Comment: I don't I'm afraid, I imagine it's a naming restriction in AAD properties - that they can't have `-` in so you need to remove them when using the client ID as part of the extension property name.